# Content viewer for .issue files

Tags: objective-c, ipad, epub

I am developing an app which will read digital publications. The format of the publications will be .issue. I would like to know how it can be unzipped to organize as a emagazine so that it can be read using an app.
Do .issue files can be read using adobe's digital content viewer only ?
Can it be uncompressed and read using our own application? If so how can it be done using obj c?

Comment: Please improve your question, I didn't get a single word from this.

Comment: I am developing an app which will read digital publications. The format of the publications will be .issue. I would like to know how it can be unzipped to organize as a emagazine so that it can be read using an app.

Comment: update your question with that comment of yours.